# Error message: (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

Tags: authentication, sql-server-2019

I created a new login for my server, but when I try logging in, I get the following error message:

> Error message: (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

I am working in SSMS v19.0.1

I ensured that permission for this login to connect to the database engine is granted and login ability is enabled.

Additionally, the Server Authentication Mode is set to allow both Windows and SQL Server Authentication methods.

I also checked that Shared Memory, TCP/IP, and Named Pipes are all Enabled (and they are in that order) in SSCM.

I restarted the server and retried the login many times.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you see the connection failure in the SQL Server logs? If so, what is the error there?

Comment: Are you sure the SQL Server service is started? Do you have a default instance or a named instance, if the latter did you specify it in the connection settings?

Comment: This is the message given in the SQL Server logs: Login failed for user 'Test User'. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: Yes, I ensured that the server is started. I'm not sure how to go about the second part of your statement. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: The error message conflicts with your statement that the instances is configured to allow both Windows and SQL auth. Does the SQL error log contain the message "Authentication mode is MIXED."?

Comment: In the Properties, the Windows and SQL Server Authentication is clicked, but the above message is the one that I am consistently getting in the error log.

Comment: I can only guess then that either you didn't restart the service, or that you are connecting to a different service than the one you think. Please supply the details I asked for on the named instance/default instance.

Comment: I believe I have a named instance, though I'm not sure I understand what you meant by "did you specify it in the connection settings".

Comment: @CRegnew, if you are using a named instance, the instance name will be specified in the connection string. Perhaps multiple instances are installed and you're viewing properties of a different instance than you're connecting to.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @DanGuzman. I'm pretty sure that I only have one instance and I'm connecting to it. I've been doing some more troubleshooting and I think I'm heading in the right direction now.

Comment: A named instance needs to connect via the name, a default instance just via the machine name. In the case of the local machine, you just do `.` for a default instance, or `.\InstanceName` for a named instance.